# Access router from Angular Dart controller

Tags: dart, angular-dart

I have a basic Angular Dart program which currently allows logging in and shows a basic dashboard when logged in.  What I would like to do is redirect to the dashboard route after a successful login.  I do not know how to access the router object from within the login controller, attempts to use DI to load in `Router` to the controller work but give me a fresh `Router` object instead of the previously initialised one (as expected).

**main.dart**

```dart
import 'package:angular/angular.dart';
import 'dart:convert' show JSON;
import 'dart:html';

class TTRouter implements RouteInitializer {

  Cookies _cookies;

  TTRouter(this._cookies);

  init(Router router, ViewFactory view) {
    router.root
      ..addRoute(
          name: 'login',
          path: '/login',
          enter: view('login.partial.html'))
      ..addRoute(
          name: 'home',
          path: '/dashboard',
          enter: view('dashboard.partial.html'));
  }

}

@NgController(
    selector: '[login-controller]',
    publishAs: 'ctrl')
class LoginController {
  Http _http;
  Scope _scope;

  LoginController(this._scope, this._http);

  login() {
    // Login API request ommitted
    // TODO: insert redirect to 'home' route here
  }
}


class TTModule extends Module {
  TTModule() {
    type(RouteInitializer, implementedBy: TTRouter);
    type(LoginController);

    factory(NgRoutingUsePushState,
        (_) => new NgRoutingUsePushState.value(false));
  }
}

main() => ngBootstrap(module: new TTModule());
```

`login()` is called using `ng-submit="ctrl.login()` from the login partial view.

I would be grateful for any comments on the structure of the code as well if I'm approaching this the wrong way.  I am new to both Dart and Angular (read/watched tutorials but this is the first app I am building on my own).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you add the router as `value` to the module instead of `type` you get the same instance every time.

```dart
TTModule() {
  value(RouteInitializer, new TTRouter());
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  Would you mind expanding how I would access this value from the controller?

Comment: There's no difference. The difference is just how you inform DI about how to handle this type. Instead of a new instance you will always receive the one provided to the `value(...)` method.

Comment: I see, I made a mistake and I've got it working now.  Many thanks!

Comment: Small further question: using `new TTRouter()` now prevents me from using DI within the TTRouter initialiser.  Is there a way around this?

Comment: I had not yet time to dive into the routing package. I took a look at https://github.com/angular/angular.dart.tutorial (e.g. Chapter 07 uses the Router). I just saw they use a different approach. I guess your code is derived from this example.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45594/discussion-between-gunter-zochbauer-and-ollie)

Answer (score 1):

**try with NgRoutingHelper.**

```dart
class LoginController {
  Http _http;
  Scope _scope;

  NgRoutingHelper locationService;
  LoginController(this._scope, this._http, NgRoutingHelper this.locationService );

  login() {
    // Login API request ommitted
    // TODO: insert redirect to 'home' route here
    locationService.router.go('home', {} );
  }
}
```

don't forget to add the service in your module

```dart
type(NgRoutingHelper );
```

Comment: `NgRoutingHelper` is an internal helper class. Avoid using it and especially modifying module bindings for it.

Answer (score 1):

You should be always getting the same instance of the `Router` -- there can only be one, otherwise unpredictable things will start happening.

```dart
class LoginController {
  Http _http;
  Scope _scope;
  Router _router;

  LoginController(this._scope, this._http, this._router);

  login() {
    _router.go('home', {} );
  }
}
```